# Compare text in column A and J and delete matching cells

Tags: vba, excel, compare, multiple-columns

Im trying to compare text in two columns.

If the text in column A exactly match any text in column B then delete the cells in both columns.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code that you have already. this way you will learn as we will explain which part is not working.

Answer (score 0):

here is something to get you started

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$16").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2)    
End Sub
```